# Can I back up data such as contacts programmatically?

Tags: android

I am designing an anti-theft application, and I would like to implement a remote backup features where simple and important data such as contacts can be moved from the lost phone to maybe another phone or via email. Is this possible? Really need some opinions on it.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried google-ing to see if there are Contact APIs for Android?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you couldn't. Make a 'myContacts' class with a bunch of strings for the properties you want to save. Create an array of myContacts. Query all of the contacts to populate your myContacts array with the value. From there spit it into xml, json, an email, or whatever.

Then to restore you can use the contacts provider. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html has details on how to do that.